# checking a string for specific pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a large string. I want to look for every `<img src="rabbit.jpeg">` and for example, replace it with `<img src="arabit.jpeg">`.
File name can be different everytime. I want to add something before the filename. Thanks

Comment: show what you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `replaceAll` function..

Try like this:

```
String line = "some text <img src=\"rabbit.jpeg\">  some text <img src=\"rabbit.jpeg\"> some text";
line = line.replaceAll("<img src=\"rabbit.jpeg\">","<img src=\"arabit.jpeg\">");
System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

İ think you are looking for replace method.

```
public class Guru99Ex1 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String S1 = new String("the quick fox jumped");
    System.out.println("Original String is ': " + S1);
    System.out.println("String after replacing 'fox' with 'dog': " + S1.replace("fox", "dog"));
    System.out.println("String after replacing all 't' with 'a': " + S1.replace('t', 'a'));

}
```

}

Java has this replace method for String. i guess it will do the job for you.